# Transparency of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uisearchbar

Lately I've noticed a strange thing in my app. While I tap on `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDiplayController` starts its tasks you can see relics from the regular `UITableView`. It wouldn't be so annoying as the regular `UITableView` is freezed but when I use custom **pull-to-refresh controller** like [`SSPullToRefresh`](https://github.com/soffes/sspulltorefresh) it's placed in inset of `UITableView` so it's always visible.

[image: transparency]

Also, it wouldn't be so eye catching if the status bar would be transculent but it's transparent and you can clearly see what's under the `UISearchBar` and **Status Bar**.
So my question is: **Is it possible to make `UISearchBar` and Status Bar opaque?**

In latest version I'm using [`AMScrollingNavBar`](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar) so this custom pull-to-refresh view has moved to the **Status Bar** but I guess if **Status Bar** is set to be Inferred it's the issue with `UISearchBar`.

Comment: try self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: @Basheer_CAD I've already done that and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UISearchBar` style to Black.

Set StatusBar to Black.